# Invalid SQL Statement in Oracle when comparing two queries using $IF$

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle DBMS and I want to try the following:

I have an entity "Flight" with an attribute "DepartureTime", I want to know the number of flights at 2 different times and compare the count, then print which time has more flights

My attempt:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(DepartureTime)   
From Flight    
WHERE DepartureTime='23:58')>   
(SELECT COUNT(DepartureTime)   
From Flight  
WHERE DepartureTime='23:00')  
 BEGIN 
PRINT 'First is bigger'    
END   
ELSE  
 BEGIN   
PRINT 'Second is bigger'  
END;
```

I am getting "Invalid SQL Statement"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not valid Oracle syntax. This looks like SQL Server.

Comment: @GMB would you mind helping? I am playing with iy on my own and just googled how I can do which resulted in this syntax

Comment: Yes, syntax incorrect. If this is a part of larger SQL procedure type thing, pls post it.

Comment: @KoushikRoy no it is not, I wrote what I wanted to accomplish at the start of the post, I am new to this so had to search about the if statement and such, that is what I got with trying, I don't care how the thing I want to do can be done as long as it is done.

Comment: You can try this - `SELECT
case when a.cnt > b.cnt then  'First is bigger'  else 'Second is bigger' end as output FROM( 
SELECT COUNT(DepartureTime) cnt   
From Flight    
WHERE DepartureTime='23:58') a,   
(SELECT COUNT(DepartureTime) cnt  
From Flight  
WHERE DepartureTime='23:00')  b;` Its not most efficient but it will do the job you are looking for.

Comment: If this one is working, shall i mark it as answer?

Comment: I will have access to oracle in around an hour so I didn't test it as of yet, I will let you know what happens when I do.

Comment: @KoushikRoy it is working, please put it as answer so I mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
SELECT case when subq1.cnt > subq2.cnt then  'First is bigger'  else 'Second is bigger' end as output 
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(DepartureTime) cnt    From Flight     WHERE DepartureTime='23:58') subq1, 
(SELECT COUNT(DepartureTime) cnt   From Flight   WHERE DepartureTime='23:00')  subq2;
```

I created two subqueries to count departure times and then compared those counts in outer query using `case-when`.
Its not the most efficient but it will meet your requirement.

Comment: thank you! btw if you are interested I posted another question that you might be able to answer too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64956724/using-multiple-nested-queries-in-oracle-dbms

Comment: accepted your edit, any further help would be appreciated :)