# Using multiple nested queries in Oracle DBMS

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select the contact info (email and phonenumber) of all employees working between 2 time ranges in shops of type market and have currently more than 2 employees working together

What I want to do: I have an entity EMPLOYEE that is the owner entity of another entity SCHEDULE, and I have a "SHOP" entity with a "shopn" attribute as foreign key of EMPLOYEE

My attempt:

```
SELECT Email, Phonenumber  
FROM EMPLOYEE  
WHERE COUNT(  
        ID = (SELECT ID_Num  
            FROM SCHEDULE     
            WHERE Start_Time <= 12:07 AND End_Time >= 12:07)  
    AND Shopn = (SELECT Shopname  
            FROM SHOP  
            WHERE Shoptype = ‘market’)
    ) > 2
```

I am getting `ORA-00934` error
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are too many mistakes in this code. Let's start with the easiest ones. What is 12:07 supposed to be in your code? Is it a string? Then put it in single quotes. What is the data type of `Start_Time` and `End_Time`? Are they strings? (If so... bad idea!)

Comment: they are of type varchar, I thought it wouldn't compare so I put equal only and it gave me that error

Comment: Put the 12:07 in single quotes, so it is a string also. Then: are the `Start_Time` and `End_Time` in the `hh24:mi` format (meaning, `'04:45'` for 4:45 AM and `'15:00'` for 3 PM? If they are not (for example: if the single-digit hours don't have the leading 0) then your comparisons won't work as intended.

Comment: yes they are like you said

Comment: @mathguy any idea about further errors? as these changes don't fix it

Comment: can you pls try this `SELECT Email, Phonenumber FROM
(SELECT Email, Phonenumber  , count(*) cnt
FROM EMPLOYEE  
WHERE  ID IN (SELECT ID_Num  
            FROM SCHEDULE     
            WHERE  start_time - to_date(to_char(trunc(start_time),'yyyymmdd'||' 12:07','yymmdd hh24:mi') >0 and 
     end_time - to_date(to_char(trunc(end_time),'yyyymmdd'||' 12:07','yymmdd hh24:mi') <0 
   )  
AND Shopn in (SELECT Shopname  
            FROM SHOP  
            WHERE Shoptype = 'market')
GROUP BY Email, Phonenumber
HAVING count(*)>2)`

Comment: Since these are time i had to convert it to a date time to compare. Logic is - if emp worked between start time >1207 and end time <1207 and if worked in market and count of employees >2

Comment: @KoushikRoy command not properly ended, added a semi colon at the end and still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```
SELECT Email, Phonenumber
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE COUNT(
ID = (SELECT ID_Num
FROM SCHEDULE
WHERE Start_Time <= 12:07 AND End_Time >= 12:07)
AND Shopn = (SELECT Shopname
FROM SHOP
WHERE Shoptype = ‘market’) ) > 2
```

Issues :

1. It seems you are trying to select id using "=" operator which will fail in case of multiple entries returned by inner query.
2. You cannot add aggregate operators in the where clause.

Probable Answer:

```
select Email, Phonenumber
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ID in (SELECT ID_Num
FROM SCHEDULE
WHERE Start_Time <= '12:07' AND End_Time >= '12:07')
AND Shopn in (SELECT Shopname
FROM SHOP
WHERE Shoptype = 'market')
and (  
select count(distinct id)
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ID in (SELECT ID_Num
FROM SCHEDULE
WHERE Start_Time <= '12:07' AND End_Time >= '12:07')
AND Shopn in (SELECT Shopname
FROM SHOP
WHERE Shoptype = 'market')) > 2;
```

Comment: when I tried to run it as it is I got a weird windows prompt, tried to put quotes between the times since they are varchar and I got command not properly ended, try putting a ";" and error remained

Comment: ‘market’ should be not used try using a conventional qoutes i have edited the script, if issue further persists removing the last condition and run. Let me know

Comment: I already did that myself as I have noticed it, I get command not properly ended, I tried removing the "WHERE Shoptype = 'market' and got the same regardless if I leave statement as is or add a ";" at the end

Comment: Yes i think you are missing a semicolumn at the end

Comment: I added it myself and still got the same, that is what I was saying

Comment: another syntax issue there was an extra ) try the latest one that should be it.